# How does the EnableAutoConfiguration spring annotation work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am no fan of gross over abstractions, <s>And i think Spring has committed a major felony.</s>

But I'm willing to overlook it this time if someone can explain the algorithm behind the 'auto' configuration.

Having a look at [spring's own javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html), It doesn't give much away other than saying that it will intelligently guess what you need and something to do about conditional beans.

Does someone know what algorithm is used to determine what needs to be loaded?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my experience as a Spring Boot user the basic factors for Spring Boot to decide on what auto-configurations will be enabled are:

1) The classes present on the classpath. For example if RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP classes are present, then the `RabbitAutoConfiguration` will be enabled. The corresponding annotation is `@ConditionalOnClass`,

2) The presence or not of user defined beans. For example, if all the Spring Data JPA is present on the classpath, Spring Boot will register a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean only if the user has not already done so. The beans registered by the user will 'override' the default ones. The relevant annotation is `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`

As @DaveSyer mentions, you can of course use Spring Boot without `@EnableAutoConfiguration` if you want to include the relevant configuration on your own. Or you could use the less drastic solution of the `exclude` field of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.  If for example you want Spring Boot to autoconfigure everything except ActiveMQ, you would use `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class)`

In my opinion, there is absolutely no felony here! You can use what you want from Spring Boot. When you don't want something it has to offer, you can easily opt out partially or completely!

Also if you want to get a look under the covers, you can add the property

`logging.level.org.springframework.boot=DEBUG`

to `application.properties` and Spring Boot will gladly give a detailed report of what was auto-configured and what wasn't

Comment: ok, So maybe I was being a little over dramatic. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7):

There is some documentation in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-locating-auto-configuration-candidates). It's not terribly complicated, and I hardly think it's a felony to just include a bunch of `@Configuration` that you might have written anyway (because that's all it does). Feel free not to use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` if you prefer to include the individual configurations individually.

Comment: The problem comes when something doesn't work as you expect.  @EnableAutoConfiguration is fine for cheap howto blogs, but a real pain to debug in anything moderately complex.  Some good documentation on this annotation and what can be disabled would be very welcome, if you have a link?

Comment: There's a link in my answer. And we have quite a few quite complex apps in production now with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so it should be fine if you go with the flow. Like I said, you can always not use it if you don't like the magic.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found what I was looking for in the logs in the end by enabling DEBUG for spring boot.  I wanted to disable the BasicErrorController because I was stuck in a Spring Security redirect loop and I wanted to handle my errors just using standard Spring MVC methods