# How Spring boot giving the dependencies and configuration?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I understand the concept of Spring boot, but I am looking for the logic how it is implemented and where it is maintaining the configuration. When we add any Starter-pom immediately it is giving the dependency and the configuration needed for it. How it automated that feature and where is that automating code in the spring boot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that is done by IDE.

Comment: I doubt it's done by the IDE. An IDE isn't required; you can build it with mvn from the command line if you wanted to.

Comment: I have gone through the Spring boot Git code and Struck with only POM files and Spring.provides files. I didn't get the logic, so came here..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the EnableAutoConfiguration spring annotation work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351581/how-does-the-enableautoconfiguration-spring-annotation-work)

Comment: Not familiar with Spring Boot, but what you are talking seems to be the work of Maven.  Maven retrieves dependencies of project transitively.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration classes for Spring Boot are in the module `spring-boot-autoconfigure`. A starter POM has a dependency on that (through the general `spring-boot-starter` module) and the required 3rd party libraries, and then the autoconfiguration for that library is activated.

Answer (score 0):

The SpringBoot project has been put there so to be more productive & build production ready app in no time. SpringBoot project referes many starter projects like `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, spring-boot-starter-logging, etc. All these starter libraries are like maven sub module projects and they add a set of libraries to respective project in turn. Like the spring-boot-starter-jdbc library adds these libraries -> `spring-jdbc,spring-tx,tomcat-jdbc`.
Now for the configuration part, spring boot has maintained another library called `spring-boot-autoconfigure` which auto configures all needed configs depending on the libraries present on your pom and the initial set of config annotation been used on the app. For Eg. if it sees ojdbc jar present in your pom then it will autoconfigure oracle datasource to your project

Answer (score 0):

From my bare understanding, this feature are not provided by Spring Boot.  It is the power of Maven.  Maven allow you to declare dependencies, and the dependencies themselves, **PLUS the transitive dependencies** will be retrieved.

The `starter` POMs are simply normal Maven POM-type artifact which declared essential dependencies, and hence, when you include in your own POM, related dependencies will be downloaded.

You may get some more understanding on Maven from [Maven Site](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) or [Maven Guide by Sonatype](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html)

Comment: Just wonder why downvote? Would like to know which part of my answer is not correct so I can fix that.